# Shadows cast by Venus

Tags: visible-light, astronomy, shadow

How and why would a shadow on earth cast by Venus differ from one cast by the Sun or Moon?

My thinking is that the shadow would be much fainter because less light is being blocked. Also, I think it would be clearer in the sense of having little fuzziness around the edge of the shadow because the light from Venus is much closer to a point source than the Sun or Moon.

Comment: Do you mean the image of Venus we see, or the slight decrease of sunlight on Earth, when Venus is in transit?

Comment: @AdrianHoward  I mean that on a clear moonless evening Venus can sometimes be seen to shine quite brightly, so much so that if you raised your hand, a shadow would be cast on the ground by Venus. How would this shadow differ from shadows cast by the Sun and Moon?

Comment: In that case, you are pretty well correct on both thoughts.